# Alternative Map API's (Like Google Maps)

Tags: maps

Trying to shortlist online map tools that can be used for a **business**.  So far I've got:

- Google Maps
- Bing Maps
- Yahoo Maps
- Openstreetmap.org
- Map quest

Can anyone think of any others?

Comment: This should be a Community Wiki

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151593/alternatives-to-google-maps-api)

Comment: [here maps](https://www.here.com)

Answer (score 40):

To get the best possible answer to this question I combine all given answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151593/alternatives-to-google-maps-api).

**Alternatives to google maps api:**

- MapTiler Cloud:
  https://cloud.maptiler.com/
- Bing Maps (Microsoft Maps) API:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/
- MapQuest:
  http://developer.mapquest.com/

  (provided by [TuxGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167885/tuxgeek))
- Mapjam:
  http://mapjam.com
- OpenStreetMap API:
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6
- Osmdroid:
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmdroid
- OpenStreetMap Android
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

  (provided by [AGrunewald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257811/agrunewald))
- GraphHopper Directions and Matrix API
  https://graphhopper.com/#directions-api

  (provided by [karussell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194609/karussell))

Comment: all in one http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Comment: There is a community wiki for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151593/alternatives-to-google-maps-api please edit it and add your information