# Alternatives to google maps api

Tags: iphone, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

**Google maps API** is great for developing location based services for mobile phones. But for some reason, the use of it is restricted for me in a special project.

E.g. if your project is in conflict with the general terms and conditions of google it is not recommended to use google maps API.

In my app, both Android and iOS, I want to display a location on a map by retrieving GPS information. Overall the API should offer a **similar scope of operation** like google maps API.

Which **alternatives** do you know? Maybe there are **open source API's**? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why can you not display location on google mapview?

Comment: I spoke to my customer yesterday and he just told me, no google maps api...I should get some more information today...but since google maps api is well integrated e.g. in android I think it is not easy to find alternative

Comment: On a Web application with lots of traffic, Google Maps can be very expensive to use. On an Android phone, I don't know if the terms are similar, but that could be one concern. In some areas, like in Tokyo (Japan) for example, the map/street data is being jealously guarded by the companies that own it, and Google Maps doesn't have access to those good maps. My point is that there could be a number of reasons why Google Maps wouldn't work for a client, but whatever reason it is, you need to find out what it is, knowing their underlying reason may save you many problems down the line.

Comment: By the way, "similar in scope" is very fuzzy. Will your map need geocoding? If so, there are some alternatives to that if needed. Also I'm surprised, but no one mentioned Atlas yet. Twelve years ago, I was using Atlas to do this very kind of thing (it was super expensive at the time, but I can only assume their prices must have gone down by now).

Comment: If your client said no to google maps, then he probably already has a solution in his head.  Find out what that is and why, and if it's illogical, challenge him on it.  He may already know the framework he is in love with.

Comment: all in one http://greatmaps.codeplex.com

Comment: Which is the best one to use for offline maps?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

To get the best possible answer to this question I combine all given answers.

**Alternatives to google maps api:**

- **MapTiler Cloud**:
  https://cloud.maptiler.com/
- **Microsoft Maps API**:
  http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx
- **Yahoo Maps API** (*discontinued* as of Sept 13,2011 in favor of [Nokia Maps](http://developer.here.com/)):
  http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/

  (provided by [Vic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115778/vic))
- **TomTom Map Toolkit API** which includes SDKs for Android, iOS and JavaScript    http://developer.tomtom.com/

  (provided by [SoWeLie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345343/sowelie))
- **CloudMade**:
  http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects

  (provided by [Adolfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182962/adolfo))
- **MapQuest**:
  http://developer.mapquest.com/

  (provided by [TuxGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167885/tuxgeek))
- **OpenStreetMap API**:
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6
- **Here.com Maps** (Formerly Nokia Maps / Ovi Maps):
  http://developer.here.com/
- **Osmdroid**:
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmdroid
- **OpenStreetMap Android**
  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

  (provided by [AGrunewald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257811/agrunewald))
- **Route-Me**:
  https://github.com/route-me/route-me

  (provided by [kiteloop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95435/kiteloop))
- **OpenLayers**:
  http://openlayers.org/

  (provided by [Arman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67381/arman))
- **Trimaps**:
  http://trimaps.com/en/
- **MapBox** http://mapbox.com/

  (provided by [Stot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832181/stot))
- **Nutiteq** http://www.nutiteq.com/

  (provided by [Martijn M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717136/martijn-m))
- **GraphHopper Directions and Matrix API** https://graphhopper.com/#directions-api

  (provided by [karussell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194609/karussell))

Answer (score 26):

2 more suggestions:

OpenStreetMap API: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Mobile Maps: https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-maps/
(powered by Idevio with map data provided by OpenStreetMap)

Answer (score 13):

1. Microsoft Maps API: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx
2. Yahoo Maps API: http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/

To name a few, unless I totally misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 12):

I would have a look at the Openstreetmap stuff http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android especially this http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmdroid a replacement for Androids Map View

Answer (score 9):

For your iOS project you could use Route-Me ([link](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/)). This is an open source framework that pretty much provides the same functionality as MapKit, but allows to integrate different map sources (e.g. Open Street Map, Cloudmade etc.). As far as I know, this is the only alternative you have on iOS.

For Android, there are various alternatives that allow you to use alternate map sources. See [this link](http://code.google.com/p/open-android-alliance/issues/detail?id=7) for a good list of options.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for just Geocoding and reverse geocoding you could check out [tinygeocoder](http://tinygeocoder.com/blog/about/).  I haven't used it myself, but it could be an option to review.

Comment: +1 for mentioning tinygeocoder. An important thing is that you DON'T have to display the results on map like with Google Maps API. I will be interested though in hearing what kind of traffic can this service withstand. My traffic is pretty small right now, but grows every day.

Answer (score 4):

Great list of alternatives to Google Maps being generated here. Good question. Not sure about your appliation - but one more from Nokia - Ovi Maps http://api.maps.ovi.com/ . They have some excellent data (they own Navtech) and incredible 3D visualization.

Answer (score 3):

<s>What about SimpleGeo?</s>

https://simplegeo.com/developers/

Seems quite promising. It's form the same people that have done:

http://polymaps.org/

I realized that it was only available for javascript sorry. But I found this one instead:

http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Answer (score 3):

TomTom has just released it's Map Toolkit API which includes SDKs for Android, iOS and JavaScript.  See http://developer.tomtom.com/.

DISCLAIMER: I work for TomTom and I created the JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Another one is MapBox

http://mapbox.com/

In their video there was foursquare shown as a user.

Answer (score 2):

Another nice one http://www.skyhookwireless.com/localfaves/

Answer (score 2):

There's Sasha Maps, which I happened to write :-)

http://www.maryanovsky.com/sasha/maps/

Written in GWT, supports all desktop browsers, iOS and Android. You will need to provide your own tiles (or find someone who will let you use theirs).

Answer (score 1):

Some location-based APIs (not map tiles) -  don't know if it would be useful for your project  - travel time calculations, public transit data and walkability (Walk Score) for maps.

http://www.walkscore.com/professional/walk-score-apis.php

(Disclaimer: I didn't write them, but I work there as front end dev - so let me know if any documentation is unclear! :D)