# Looking for an open source or relatively cheap one time fee, for a map of the world with plotting capabilities in javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, maps, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151593/alternatives-to-google-maps-api)

I can't use google maps because their terms limit me as my service will charge a fee. But, google maps is overkill anyway. Just looking for a nice map of the world that we can plot some points on to show visitors online. Some caveats:

- The map should be able to cluster (it's possible there are 10,000 points on the map, cluster would make it easier to see and faster to render)
- Allowed for commercial use
- Doesn't need to zoom to street level, but a little zoom is nice.
- NOT FLASHBASED as this would need to work across iOS as well as windows.

Comment: not sure where the duplicate is?? I think my requirements are different

Answer (score 0):

May [**Openlayers**](http://openlayers.org) help you? You can use many providers and add whatever you want over the map. Even accessible controls.

[Examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) provided