# directions api which provider to use

Tags: php, maps, directions

I've got a question about directional services. There's a similar question on which I gave a reaction, but there's no response so I ask my question again. Sorry if this is double!
The post I'm talking about is [Alternatives to google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151593/alternatives-to-google-maps-api)

Now my question: 
I need to make a route description for a courier that had to drive every day to deliver things. It's just a list with waypoints that needs to be in the right order for driving. I'm talking about 10 to 20 waypoints in a route. First I tried Google, I finished the script and they have max 8 waypoints. I can't take the pro account because it's way to expensive!!

Which provider is the best to do this. I'm building this in a cronjob that calculates the route every day, so I can't use javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe http://openstreetmap.org is something for you. There its also possible to [set waypoints](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Managing_waypoints_with_OSM).

- [An overview of php frameworks for openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks)
- [PHProute](http://www.phproute.org/)

Comment: The openstreetmap is a good option I think. Not really sure about the PHProute though, it is still in development. Have you seen the mapquest service? http://developer.mapquest.com/ 
Anybody has experience with this?