# is there any Apple Direction API?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I need to know, is there any apple direction api by which we can get direction detail between two points(coordinates) same as we can do it via google api.

I need to draw route between two points within app. i do not want to open apple map by using new IOS SDK 6 MKMapItem class.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609344/alternative-map-apis-like-google-maps here is the different list of map api

Answer (score 0):

Nope, except you can send the user to the Maps app for directions.  You can do this by creating an [MKDirectionRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011745) object.

If you want the user to stay in your app, you need to do the routing yourself, or use a different API.

Answer (score 0):

MKDirections

[Apple class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/)