# How to do animation and design mark point like this on google map in android

Tags: android, dictionary, animation, marker

Like a title, I want to make marker of my google map like this, and animation like in this picture. Please can anyone help me how to do this or just give me a keyword so I can search for it.Thanks!

[image: Animation of point]

Comment: You can see how to do it in this link. (you forgot to add the links :D)

Comment: I'm sorry i just add. Please look again and help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do now know how to make that exactly with Google Maps. Maybe you can use an alternative option to google Maps. With google maps, all I know is that you can change the marker image. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=es-419#personalizar_la_imagen_de_los_marcadores).

And maybe [this for alternatives to GMaps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609344/alternative-map-apis-like-google-maps)

Comment: It may help. But can I just write code to make icon and animation all buy myself.